# Vinyl converter spins 35.3 RPM -- How to correct?

Tags: software-recommendation

My new "Numark PT-01 USB" turntable/vinyl converter actually spins 35.3 RPM instead of 33.3.  Notes sound slightly sharp.  Is there a good software to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just about any audio editing software should be able to do this for you.  You simply need a "stretch" or "speed" adjustment.  If you don't know of any software, Audacity is a popular free option.  It's probably overkill for your needs, but should allow you to stretch the audio out to slow it down.